# How to connect to SQL Server with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, node-modules

I am connecting to SQL Server from Nodejs, but it's throwing this error:

```
C:\SMS\Server\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:70
          err = new ConnectionError(err)
                ^

ConnectionError: Failed to connect to SVGGNAPP17:undefined - 605B0000:error:0A000102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\statem_lib.c:1986:

    at C:\SMS\Server\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:70:17
    at Connection.onConnect (C:\SMS\Server\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1012:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:26)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:512:28)
    at Connection.emit (C:\SMS\Server\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1040:18)
    at Connection.socketError (C:\SMS\Server\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1395:12)
    at C:\SMS\Server\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:2402:25
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to SVGGNAPP17:undefined - 605B0000:error:0A000102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\statem_lib.c:1986:

      at Connection.socketError (C:\SMS\Server\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1395:28)
      at C:\SMS\Server\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:2402:25
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    code: 'ESOCKET',
    isTransient: undefined
  }
}
```

I'm using Node.js v19.6.0

This is my connecting string:

```
const config = {
  server: "SVGGNAPP17\\SQLEXPRESS",
  database: "***",
  user: "***",
  password: "***",
  options: {
    trustServerCertificate: true,
    trustedConnection: true,
  },
};
```

I have tried connecting to another server and its working fine but to this specific server its throwing the above mentioned error..

Comment: Aside... pick an authentication method: is it going to be Active Directory/Kerberos/Windows authentication using the current process's authentication token due to `trustedConnection: true`, or is it going to be SQL Logon username-password based authentication using the `user: ...` and `password: ...` properties? Choose one, remove the other.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76487398/edit) your question to include the output from `SELECT @@VERSION` executed against the target instance. The `SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol` part of the error message is telling you that your target server is too old to support modern TLS protocol versions, or it's too new to be supported by the version of the `mssql` package you have installed.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning then how can i resolve this issue ?